# form suddenly not posting correctly yii

Tags: yii

it was working fine the past few weeks but i have no idea what happened...
Every time I submit it gives me `user_product_id` cannot be blank.

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'user_product_id', 
    CHtml::listData(Product::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('store_id'=>$store_id)),'product_id','product_name'),
    array('prompt'=>'Select Your Product'));
        ?>
```

Not sure if this is related to the same problem, but within the same controller, it also gives me an error saying trying to get non-object, when it is an object.

```
$model->target_id = Product::model()->findbypk($product_id)->name_id;
```

`var_dump` gives me an integer for `$product_id` as well as the entire expression...

Comment: `Product::model()->findbypk($product_id)` may returns empty.

Comment: Check your validation rules. It looks like one of your rules is not validating.